How to Convert HEIC to PNG/JPG with Node.js
Is there a way to convert HEIC images to png/jpg using node js?
I'm currently on a nest js project and I tried multiple packages and none of them worked!
I tried  heic-convert, sharp, and heic2any
The only thing that worked for me is installing imageMagick on the machine and thats not an option for me.

Brother, heic-convert should work well, I just ran this code and it worked well for me.
const fs = require("fs/promises");
const convert = require("heic-convert");

(async () => {
  try {
    const inputBuffer = await fs.readFile(__dirname + "/sample.heic");
    const outputBuffer = await convert({
      buffer: inputBuffer, // the HEIC file buffer
      format: "JPEG", // output format
      quality: 1, // the jpeg compression quality, between 0 and 1
    });

    await fs.writeFile("./result.jpg", outputBuffer);
    console.log("done");
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
})();

please try this on a fresh nodejs app and let me know.

try this lib: heic-convert
i belive it ll help you.
If you still can't solve, there is this lib: Sharp.
This lib is faster than image magick.

Thank you for your answer, but as I mentioned in my question I tried both of these  packages and they didn't work for me
